# Elegant solution to converting a std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>> into a std::vector<T*>

Tags: c++, boost, std

I did not find exactly the same question.

Is there a way to convert a:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>>
```

into a non safe version:

```
std::vector<T*>
```

without doing a for loop and using .get() on each element of the original vector ?

Comment: Is the "in a 1 liner" requirement really important? (i.e. is this for code golf or for real code?)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: I wanted to avoid the answer where you would iterate trough each element of the vector and find an elegant solution. The 1 liner is not really a requirement and I edited the question (thank you)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::transform(safe.begin(), safe.end(), std::back_inserter(unsafe),
               boost::bind(&boost::shared_ptr<T>::get, _1));
```